# Replicate row in Pandas dataframe based on condition and change values for a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time-series

```
Start_Year   End_Year   Opp1              Opp2          Duration
1500         1501       ['A','B']        ['C','D']      1
1500         1510       ['P','Q','R']    ['X','Y']      10
1520         1520       ['A','X']        ['C']          0
...          ....        ........        .....          ..
1809         1820       ['M']            ['F','H','Z']  11
```

My dataset(csv file format) is of armed wars fought between different entities(countries, states, and factions represented by Capital letters A, B, P, Q etc as lists in Opp1(opposition) and Opp2 columns. Start_Year and End_Year are the years about when the war started and when it ended. The Duration column is created by subtracting values of End_Year to Start_Year.

I want to replicate those rows with Duration greater than 0 by the factor of the Duration of war i.e if duration is 6 years then replicate that row 6 times and decrease the Duration values by 1 and increase the Start_Year by 1 for every replication in replicated rows and keep the values in other columns same.(if duration is 1 year then it should replicate the row 2 times so that duration becomes 0 years for every war after replication to last step).
My desired output column is like this:

I have no clue how to proceed with something like this as I am a beginner in data science and analysis. So pardon me for not showing any trial codes here.

```
Start_Year   End_Year   Opp1              Opp2          Duration
1500         1501       ['A','B']        ['C','D']      1
1501         1501       ['A','B']        ['C','D']      0
1500         1510       ['P','Q','R']    ['X','Y']      10
1501         1510       ['P','Q','R']    ['X','Y']      9
1502         1510       ['P','Q','R']    ['X','Y']      8
1503         1510       ['P','Q','R']    ['X','Y']      7
1504         1510       ['P','Q','R']    ['X','Y']      6
1505         1510       ['P','Q','R']    ['X','Y']      5
....         ....       .............    ........       ..
1510         1510       ['P','Q','R']    ['X','Y']      0
1520         1520       ['A','X']        ['C']          0
...          ....        ........        .....          ..
1809         1820       ['M']            ['F','H','Z']  11
1810         1820       ['M']            ['F','H','Z']  10
....         ....       .....            .............. ..
1820         1820       ['M']            ['F','H','Z']  0
```

Edit:1
Some example dataset
[The Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkudR.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) to repeat the rows [`Duration times`] based on column `Duration` and then using [`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) you can add increasing cumulative values to the `start_year` column.

##### Reading data

```
data = [[1500, 1501, ['A','B'], ['C','D'], 1],
        [1500, 1510, ['P','Q','R'], ['X','Y'], 10],
        [1520, 1520, ['A','X'], ['C'], 0],
        [1809, 1820, ['M'], ['F','H','Z'], 11]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Start_Year', 'End_Year', 'Opp1', 'Opp2', 'Duration'])
```

##### Repeating the values

```
mask = df['Duration'].gt(0)
df1 = df[mask].copy()
df1 = df1.loc[df1.index.repeat(df1['Duration'] + 1)]
```

##### Assigning increasing values to each group

```
df1['Start_Year'] += df1[['Start_Year', 'End_Year', 'Opp1', 'Opp2']].astype(str).groupby(['Start_Year', 'End_Year', 'Opp1', 'Opp2']).cumcount()
```

##### Generating output

```
df1['Duration'] = df1['End_Year'] - df1['Start_Year']
df = pd.concat([df1, df[~mask]]).sort_index(kind = 'mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)
```

This gives us the expected output :

```
    Start_Year  End_Year       Opp1       Opp2  Duration
0         1500      1501     [A, B]     [C, D]         1
1         1501      1501     [A, B]     [C, D]         0
2         1500      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]        10
3         1501      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]         9
4         1502      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]         8
5         1503      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]         7
6         1504      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]         6
7         1505      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]         5
8         1506      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]         4
9         1507      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]         3
10        1508      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]         2
11        1509      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]         1
12        1510      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]         0
13        1520      1520     [A, X]        [C]         0
14        1809      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]        11
15        1810      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]        10
16        1811      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]         9
17        1812      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]         8
18        1813      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]         7
19        1814      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]         6
20        1815      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]         5
21        1816      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]         4
22        1817      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]         3
23        1818      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]         2
24        1819      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]         1
25        1820      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]         0
```

##### Alternatively

You can also try the other way around after `Repeating the values` by assigning Duration in first decreasing cumulatively. And then calculating the 'Start_Year' again

```
df1['Duration'] = df1[['Start_Year', 'End_Year', 'Opp1', 'Opp2']].astype(str).groupby(['Start_Year', 'End_Year', 'Opp1', 'Opp2']).cumcount(ascending=False)
df1['Start_Year'] = df1['End_Year'] - df1['Duration']
df = pd.concat([df1, df[~mask]]).sort_index(kind = 'mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)
```

##### Output :

This gives you same expected output:

```
    Start_Year  End_Year       Opp1       Opp2  Duration
0         1500      1501     [A, B]     [C, D]         1
1         1501      1501     [A, B]     [C, D]         0
2         1500      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]        10
3         1501      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]         9
4         1502      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]         8
5         1503      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]         7
6         1504      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]         6
7         1505      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]         5
8         1506      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]         4
9         1507      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]         3
10        1508      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]         2
11        1509      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]         1
12        1510      1510  [P, Q, R]     [X, Y]         0
13        1520      1520     [A, X]        [C]         0
14        1809      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]        11
15        1810      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]        10
16        1811      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]         9
17        1812      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]         8
18        1813      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]         7
19        1814      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]         6
20        1815      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]         5
21        1816      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]         4
22        1817      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]         3
23        1818      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]         2
24        1819      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]         1
25        1820      1820        [M]  [F, H, Z]         0
```

You can reset the index using [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

##### Summary :

Basically, what we have done here is duplicated rows based on value from column `Duration` with condition.

We saved the rows which could have got vanished on using [`pandas.Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) to repeat the rows [`Duration value times`] and once we replicated and applied logic on the rows with `Duration > 0` replacing column values by subsequent `increasing/decreasing` cumulative values using [`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) we concatenated both the `dataframe` and sorted them on `index` using [`pandas.DataFrame.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) since the index was also supposed to be repeated when we used [`pandas.Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) to repeat the rows [`Duration value times`]. Hence the sort on index would give us the dataframe in same order as it was in the original dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same method as the other answer posted. But I think its a bit simplified:

```
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: x.repeat(df['Duration'].iloc[x.index]+1))
counts = df2.loc[df.Duration>1].groupby(['Start_Year', 'End_Year']).cumcount()
df2.loc[df.Duration>1,'Duration'] -= counts
df2.loc[df.Duration>1,'Start_Year'] += counts
df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['Start_Year', 'Duration'], ignore_index=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(df.assign(Duration = df['Duration'].map(lambda x: np.arange(0,x+1)[::-1])) #create a list of decending numbers from duration and replace duration column
.explode('Duration') #use duration column to create additional rows
.assign(Start_Year = lambda x: x['Start_Year']
    .add(x.groupby(level=0)
    .cumcount()))
    .reset_index(drop=True)) #use groupby cumcount which creates list of ascending numbers and add to year to increase year by one for each row
```

or

```
(df.assign(Start_Year = [range(i,j+1) for i,j in zip(df['Start_Year'],df['End_Year'])])
.explode('Start_Year')
.assign(Duration = lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount(ascending=False)))
```